# Phpunit cannot find test, No test executed(Laravel)

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5.5

I am using phpunit in laravel 5.5.

When I run test using

```
vendor/bin/phpunit .
```

it shows the error

```
no tests excucted.
```

In phpunit.xml file I set suffix of test directories.

But I don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

**The solution** is here:

https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.1/installation.html#windows

Answer (score 0):

Can u share more details of your work ? If you are new in laravel can follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uYXAcit_Sg&list=PL3VM-unCzF8iPERY07XRw0JXG_c50CapR . there is step by step guideline

Answer (score 0):

I write this in case someone from **Laravel 8** come and found the similar error.

Today I learn about TDD and follow a tutorial in Youtube. in one phase I create a test function with similar name as the tutorial explained,
.
But then come the error "No Test Executed!" appear.

Similar to this question.
I already check and make sure that the file name is suffix-ed with 'Test' word.
.
I don't know whats wrong. But then After digging around, it turns out that in Laravel 8 (or maybe prior version also), the test FUNCTION NAME have to be prefixed with Test.

e.g.

`public function check_family()` => won't work

`public function test_check_family()` => work